# Quantile 0.95 or 0.98 in Poisson/Nbinom distribution give value out of distribution (R)

Tags: r, distribution, quantile

I am using R to count quantiles like 0.95, 0.98 etc.

```
qpois(0.98, f_pois$estimate[[1]])
qnbinom(0.98, size=f_pois$estimate[[1]], mu=f_nbinom$estimate[[2]])
```

My concern is that I get values 11 and 14 and my discrete distribution is movie rates from 1 to 10... So the quantiles are out of bound... Can it be fixed or is it ok?

Comment: It *might* be OK, depending on what you're actually trying to do, but in general you shouldn't model a *bounded* variable (0-10) using an *unbounded* distribution (Poisson, negbinom, etc. [0-infinity]). There aren't a huge number of convenient options for bounded discrete variables (binomial, beta-binomial ...)

Comment: You could use quantiles estimated directly from your data. That way they will never be out of range.